# Reinitialize Enum values for every Unit Test in Java

Tags: java, class, enums, initialization

I wrote an enum class for SnackType for a vending machine with the quantity and the price. I want the quantity to reinitialize every time a new test is called. However what I am running into the a problem where if a test changes the value of quantity, then the changed value carried over to the next test.

```
public enum SnackType{
    CHIPS(20, 1), CHOCOLATE(20, 2), CHEWING_GUM(20, .5);
    int amount;
    final double price;
    SnackType(int quantity, double price)
    {
        this.amount = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int quantity(){
        return this.amount;
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return this.price;
    }
    public void subquantity()
    {
        this.amount -= 1;
    }

}
```

Here are some examples of my tests

```
 @Test
    void buying_unavailable_quantity_of_a_snack_should_fail() {
        while (snackMachine.chewingGums().quantity() > 0) {
            snackMachine.insertMoney(Money.QUARTER_DINAR);
            snackMachine.insertMoney(Money.QUARTER_DINAR);

            snackMachine.buySnack(SnackType.CHEWING_GUM);
        }
```

`insertMoney()`don't worry about this function
`buySnack()`this function subtracts the quantity

```
Money buySnack(SnackType snack){
        if(snack.quantity()==0){
            throw new IllegalStateException("can't buy snack quantity zero");
        }
        else if (this.CUSTOMERS_MONEY.value.doubleValue() >= snack.getPrice()){
            snack.subquantity();

    }
```

I know the quantity of the chewing gum will become 0 at the end of this test and then the test will fail but I don't want the 0 to carry over to the other tests.

Answer (score 9):

Enum values should never be mutable in the first place. From [the Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) (emphasis added):

> An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined **constants**.

If you want a mutable value associated with an enum key, use a `Map`. You could use any type of `Map` (e.g. a `HashMap`, `TreeMap`), but because the key is an `Enum`, the best choice is `EnumMap`:

```
EnumMap<SnackType, Integer> quantities = new EnumMap<>(SnackType.class);
```

Comment: I did something where I gave each Machine its own instances of SnackTypes
`public class SnackMachine {

    public static int DEFAULT_QUANTITY = 20;
    public Money money_inside = new Money(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0));
    public Money CUSTOMERS_MONEY = new Money(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0));
    public SnackType chewing = SnackType.CHEWING_GUM;
    public SnackType chips = SnackType.CHIPS;
    public SnackType chocolate = SnackType.CHOCOLATE;
`
Should this solve the problem? But im running into the same problem

Comment: @DuniaAlrabadi Dont put such information into comments. If required, update your question instead.